# Keyboard Shortcut to Focus on an App in Mac OS

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I have about 5-6 applications that I have open on my Mac which I constantly switch between all day long. I currently use Command-Tab to do most of my switching but Ideally I'd like to set my own shortcuts like Control-Command-[0-9] to toggle between my most used apps as it would be much faster for me. I looked at the keyboard shortcuts menu in the System Preferences but I couldn't find a way to make it simply focus on a particular window. Any input on how I could acheive this?

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: Should go to http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use AppleScript and define some custom keyboard shortcuts to call the correct script.

For example:

```
tell application 'Finder' to activate
```

Set that to Control+Command+0

```
tell application 'Safari' to activate
```

Set that to Control+Command+1

... and so on

I know that System Preferences can define custom keyboard shortcuts, but I'm if they can run scripts. Something like Quicksilver or other 'productivity' addon software definitely can.

Comment: Quicksilver did the trick, thanks! Didn't even need AppleScript. I had to go to preferences in Quicksilver and enable the "activate" action and once that was done I was able to assign shortcuts to them. Works like a dream and makes switching windows MUCH easier.

Comment: I also add `do shell script "open -a Safari"` to ensure it will be started, if it doesn't run already.

Answer (score 4):

[Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) can do this as well.. among several other switching, searching tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Quicksilver](http://www.blacktree.com/) or [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html)